# DC motor flyback diode get very hot (then roasted)

Tags: mosfet, diodes, pwm, flyback, gate-driving

My motor works with 5V and consume about between 6 A and 8 A , controlled by ESC with PWM  , and there is 1n4007 flyback diode to protect it ,
when i am working with PWM frequency = 350 Hz ( it works fine )
but with  frequency = 15000 Hz  **the flyback diode get on fire and make smoke then get roasted .**
this happen just after turning on and off the motor many times consecutively while it is still spinning .

Note : i add new diode and I notice that it is getting hot when motor goes on and off many times consecutively .

why is that happen ? is there any solution ?

Note : the mosfet is cool only the flyback diode is getting hot.

this is my ESC :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a schematic. However, a 1N4007 is too slow as a flyback diode.

Comment: @DKNguyen Do you have any alternatives ?

Comment: Why is this a copy of the previous question? Since knowing what diode and how fast your pwm is makes the question clearer. You can get suitable high speed diodes out of old PC/ATX power supplies. Something like a SR104 or HR104 will work much better. R2 should be 10Ohms and R3 10K or greater. With a better choice of mosfet you can get rid of the opto and other garbage.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably overheating because the diode is too low amperage.

But a a 1N4007 is a 50/60Hz rectifier diode so it's too slow as a flyback diode. You need a faster diode like a Schotky diode.

A faster replacement for a 1N4007 is a 1N4448, but it will still probably overheat due to amperage. You need a bigger fast diode.

If you're low on big diodes, you can try connecting an NMOS in place of the diode and tying the gate to the NMOS's source terminal so the MOSFET never conducts in the forward direction. That makes use of the MOSFET's parasitic body diode (you can actually see it in the MOSFET symbol in your schematic). That body diode would be bigger than a 1N4007 if your MOSFET is big. It's not ideal, but it works in a  pinch.

Comment: thanks for your advice , but I need really  ideal solution , i don't want that  (mosfet working as diode ) to get hot or fire up .

Comment: Then go parts searching on Mouse or Digikey. You can also use an RC snubber instead of a diode which is faster because it is always there, it doesn't have to turn on like a diode, but doesn't clamp the voltage spike to a fixed level. Instead it provides an AC current path for the motor inductance to circulate and absorbs some of the voltage spike which slows down the rise so it doesn't get as high as it otherwise would. Use ceramic caps and a low value resistor (3-10 Ohms probably). 0.1uF or as much as you can if you have it and don't feel like doing math.

Comment: It's difficult to go wrong with a "fast" type diode that just has the same current rating as your MOSFET. A Schotky diode is one type of fast diode. A lot forward voltage helps too since that means less power dissipation in the diode (something which is also a feature of Schotky didoes). I wouldn't split hairs over it.

Comment: thanks a lot , I really appreciate your effort , but i need a reference of component or electronic  schematic to be the replace of the diode to support this circumstances  , a don't want to design one by my self

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Flyback_diode   Good suggestion to use the FET body diode in a pinch but not as good as a Half Bridge (?)

Comment: FREDs are pretty good for flyback diodes too. Lower leakage and higher reverse voltage than a Schottky, but not quite as fast.

Comment: Also a 4007 is a 1A diode and the energy in a 5A motor can easy surpass that; add the recovery charge due to it's slowness and it's toast

Answer (score 0):

Even 10 1N4001 diodes in parallel would be better than 1.

But each diode adds 20 pF at 0V so operating 15 kHz with very fast rise times and 8 mohm RdsOn is out of the question (poof).  So operating at low PWM rates, as you were doing,  is wise as long as it doesn't alias or interfere with the max RPM commutation on the armature.

Operating at high frequency PWM also ensures the diode operates in CCM Continuous Conduction Mode with for a 400 mOhm 1A diode with a 5A motor will burn it out not even counting capacitance/

Normally you look up fast Avalanche power diodes for this application if looking for diodes.

But I would be looking for a MOSFET half bridge or full bridge rated for much more than your motor current.